# Django manytomany field shows model name and id via model form, but not the attributes

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a manytomany in my model

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ManyToManyField('A')
```

and a model form:

```
class BForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
        model = B

        fields = ['a']
        labels = {'a': 'A'}
```

I would now like to represent the Manytomany field via the model form:

```
{% for field in BForm %}
    {{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```

It works with every field, the problem is that the manytomany field shows as values:

```
A(1)
A(2)
A(3)
A(4)
A(5)
A(6)
...
```

I would like to have the names from the model there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've described suggests when you're outputting the `field` it's showing your the string representation of `A()` which you'd like to display the `name` value in each case, not the ID which is default.

Consider my `Profile` model;

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        verbose_name=_('User'),
        to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='profile',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    def __str__(self):
        """
        String representation
        """
        return f'User Profile for: {self.user}'
```

This has a `str` method to customise what the string representation of the model instance says.

So in your case you'd write a string method like;

```py
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        """
        String representation
        """
        return f'{self.name}'
```

If you need to access fields on the related model for queries or in your forms etc the double underscore is used and detailed here; [Django: query spanning multiple many-to-many relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883461/django-query-spanning-multiple-many-to-many-relationships/2883789)